# Product page XML file

Tags: layout, xml, local.xml

Taking this page as a reference:

http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/eighth/phone5.html

I would like to add a custom CMS block under 'Add to wishlist'/'Add to Compare'/'Share'.

I can't find the right reference for this part in the XML files of Magento.

Comment: "You'll love [AOE_TemplateHints](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints), I guarantee it."

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this template implements that area, but if you want to specifically place it in the template, you'll need to do something like this below.   I have not had time to test this exact code.

Create the block and add it to the product detail page, be sure to set name and block_id:

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="my-custom-block">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my-block-id</block_id></action>
    </block>
  </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then you'll need to edit the template file `catalog/product/view.phtml` and output it where you want it to go:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my-custom-block') ?>
```

Comment: should be `reference name="product.info"`,otherwise `getChildHtml` won't work there